# switching between two wifi-network using command prompt

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am trying to switch between wifi,whichever is reachable.For ex-My PCs are connected to a different wifi network and if that wifi network goes down (not wifi signal but the connectivity) switch to another wifi. I am able to create a script but there is a downtime of 1 seconds.I dont want any downtime.Thanks.

```
:start 

timeout /t 180 

netsh wlan connect name = "duddu_CORE" interface = "wi-fi" 

Ping 8.8.8.8 -n 6 | FIND /I "TTL" 

if errorlevel 0 ( echo success 

) else ( 

netsh wlan connect name = "TP-LINK_D6BC" interface = "wi-fi" ) 

goto start
```

Comment: Have you considered upgrading the equipment? If I read this right you have two separate ISP connections, put a dual wan router as the core, setup wan fail over. You can even setup AP roaming in this config so all client devices will switch to the working ISP. I would recommend checking out pfsense/opensense

Comment: Thanks man.But i wanted a script without the dual wan router.

Answer (score 1):

You're pinging the address 6 times before checking whether it was successful or not. This is going to take some time if the connectivity is down so you're already faced with some seconds of delay there.

Then you also need to take into account the time your computer needs to authenticate with the new network. This is always going to take some time as well.

The bottom line is that you're always going to be faced with some kind of interruption. Even if you improve your connectivity detection, the authentication process is going to take a bit of time.

Comment: There's got to be a way sir.I am ok with that 6 seconds of Ping  but i m nt ok when after 180 seconds i get a downtime of 1 seconds while connecting duddu_CORE.  This line:

netsh wlan connect name = "duddu_CORE" interface = "wi-fi"

Comment: Well, to improve switching performance you might want to consider setting up your network with a fixed IP address rather than using DHCP.